# Есть ли какая-нибудь консольная утилита для изменения размера изображения из буфера обмена (Windows/Linux)?

Tags: linux, windows, изображения, консоль, буферизация

Необходимо скопированное в **буфер обмена** изображение (jpg,png как минимум) "на лету" минимально обработать - уменьшить размер (**ширина/высота**) до заданных заранее. Это нужно для быстрой обработки картинок из интернета.
Ограничения:

1. Это можно сделать в обычных графических редакторах, но когда
   картинок много, то приходится проводить лишние манипуляции, это
   неудобно
2. Все, что нашел поиском - работает с файлами, про буфер
   обмена ничего не встретил (надеюсь, я ошибся)
3. Желательно наличие дистрибутива и на Windows, и на Linux, ну или хотя бы что-то одно
4. Возвращать результат можно так же в буфер, или в файл, это не
       критично

Кто-нибудь что-то подскажет?

Comment: Если вы хотите просто пакетно обрабатывать файлы, то для этого не нужен буфер обмена (да и нет такого понятия в _линуксе_; есть в иксах). Вместо этого можно написать простейший цикл с обходом переданных ему файлов и обработкой их через `mogrify` из состава ImageMagick. Если хотите, то можно оператор пайпа | рассматривать как своеобразный буфер обмена :)

Comment: Оказывается, ImageMagick в винде таки может: http://www.illari.ru/help/imagemagick/index.html, искать по слову "clipboard".

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, спасибо. Нужна работа именно с буфером обмена, т.к. копирую картинки из интернета. Вижу, можно поиграться с сохранением буфера в файл с помощью `convert clipboard: filename.png`, а потом редактировать как угодно.

Comment: Так уж сразу и ресайзить как нужно, на то он и конверт...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скрипты для изменения размера картинки в буфере обмена (с сохранением соотношения сторон, заданный размер устанавливается для бОльшей стороны) с помощью [imageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) и [xclip](https://github.com/astrand/xclip).

**В Windows:**

```
convert -resize <size> clipboard: clipboard:
```

Создаем обертку для быстрого вызова:

```
echo convert -resize %1 clipboard: clipboard: > %systemroot%\resize_clip.cmd
```

**В Linux:**

```
$ nano /home/USER/resize.sh

#!/bin/bash
SIZE=$1
FILE="/tmp/clipboard.png"
# сохраняем из буфера во временный файл
xclip -selection cli -t image/png -o > $FILE
# проводим нужные манипуляции
convert -resize $SIZE $FILE $FILE
# копируем обратно в буфер обмена
xclip -selection cli -t image/png -i $FILE
```

Создаем симлинк для быстрого вызова:

```
$ sudo ln -s /home/USER/resize.sh /usr/local/bin/resize_clip
```

**Использование:**

```
resize_clip 150
```

В результате измененная картинка сохраняется там же в буфере.

(скрипт назвал `resize_clip` для предотвращения конфликта имен с другой системной командой `resize` в Linux)